# HD videos plays well on youtube but lags when downloaded and played in VLC(latest!) solution?

Tags: video, youtube, vlc, lag

HD videos (both 1080 and 720p) play well online on youtube but when I download them using IDM and play them in VLC they lag and a lot of disturbance. But the 480P videos play well both in VLC and online. Does any one know what is going wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You probably don't have hardware acceleration enabled.

Comment: I'm probably replying too late.. No worries thanks for your reply.
But I have figured out the problem that IDM doesn't download youtube HD videos. Cuz when i play 1080p videos downloaded from torrent they play fine. So the problem is where associated with IDM and youtube.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I also have a same problem here and i found out that if you use youtube web downloader (file2hd for example) instead of one click download (or whatever its feature name), HD quality can be achieve without any lag.